# Switched Server Associated with a ManagedChannel in gRPC Java

Tags: java, grpc-java

​

​I am building a sample GRPC app in Java and I need help in the following case​.

​Assume 2 GRPC Servers (Server A & B) are running. When Server A goes down, I want to connect to server B.​ I will know what the Server B is only after Server A goes down.

​I don't want to reinitialise the Stubs and ManagedChannel when switching from Server A to Server B or write retry logic on the stub invocation part explicitly for this requirement.​

[​This is the code](https://github.com/anantharaman93/grpc-failover-test/blob/main/src/main/java/com/ananth/grpc/Test.java) I am trying...​

​My requirement is I want to capture the request failure to server A somehow so that I can switch the actual server I want to connect to by using some logic like `HostSwitcher` specified there.​

​Need help with this.​ ​Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The default load balancing policy in gRPC is "pick_first", which will walk the list of addresses that the name resolver finds, and connect to the first one that works. So in the event that the first server goes down but the second remains up, the client would reconnect to the second server.

So I think your solution in this case is a matter of getting the name resolver to resolve both server A and B. If you want the client to prefer A, then the address for A should come first.

Comment: I will only know what the Server B is after Server A goes down. So only my question is how to handle this case.